# Update selection indices of bokeh circle with TapTool

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I'm having trouble with a CustomJS callback on the TapTool. I would like to force the selection of the 50 points after the one clicked. Therefore I have made a javascript callback that modify the list of indices selected in the datasource and should update the plot. I can see, with the console, that the datasource   is updated but the plot is not.

I have made a test version from the documentation example

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html

but it doesn't work neither. Is it because there is a different way to update the plot when the selection is changed ?

Here is the test version I have made :

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show

output_notebook()

x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.circle('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var l_selected=source.selected;
    var indices = l_selected['1d'].indices;
    if(indices.length <= 1) {
        var new_indices = Array.from(new Array(50), (x,i) => i + indices[0]);
        l_selected['1d'].indices=new_indices;
    }
    source.selected=l_selected;
    console.log(source.selected)
    source.change.emit();
""")


slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

plot.add_tools(TapTool(callback=callback))

layout = column(slider, plot)

show(layout)
```

I do not know if it can be useful, but I am using the 0.12.16 version of Bokeh and I am trying to make it work in a Jupyter notebook

Comment: After 0.12.15 source.selected['1d'].indices should just be source.selected.indices

Comment: Oh ok that's all ... That's clearly disappointing. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seb gave the answer in comments. Since bokeh 0.12.15 `source.selected['1d']` became `source.selected.indices`